# Android webview doesn't stream dropbox video

Tags: android, video, webview, stream, dropbox

I am trying to stream a video stored on dropbox on android's webview but only a blank space is
displayed, my code is below :

```
activity_web_view.xml

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/webView"
    android:text="Description" >

</TextView>
</RelativeLayout>


public class WebViewA extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("https://www.dropbox.com/s/XXXX/video.mp4?dl=0?client_id=XXXX");

 }
}
```

I have also tried the following Urls on webView.loadUrl(), but none
of them work, only a blank space appears :

```
"https://dl.dropbox.com/s/XXXX/video1.mp4?dl=0?client_id=XXXX"
"https://dl.dropbox.com/s/XXXX/video2.mp4?dl=1?client_id=XXXX"
"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/XXXX/video1.mp4"

"https://www.dropbox.com/s/XXXX/video1.mp4?dl=0"
```

if I try http://www.google.com it works, I have also seen some tutorials
with dropbox addresses that have an 'u' instead of an 's' like

```
"https://www.dropbox.com/u/..."
```

does WebView only works with dropbox urls with an 'u', if so how can I
get that type of address.

Comment: Cross-linking with the Dropbox API forum: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=120771.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in trying to get answers from two different sources, also, people who are used to look for answers here will find the answer, and people who look in Dropbox API forum will find it there, is better to spread knowledge, at the end more people have the answer and innovation grows.

Comment: Agreed, as I said on the other thread. :-)